# Unknown characters in response string

Tags: node.js, dom, encoding, http-headers, cross-domain

I am trying to get remote `DOM` from my Node.js server. Generally, I get  right response , but in some case, I get symbols like this

> +؃�Lc���B�J�D��I�д

Here are my headers

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
res.header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate, sdch");
```

What can I do to get the right `DOM`?

Comment: Can you put your code where getting the response?

Comment: app.post("/check", function(req, res) {
    var link = req.body.url;
       request(link, function (error, response, body) {
           if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
               res.json({ body: body });
           }
       });
    });

Answer (score 0):

Probably the content is being truncated at some point of time. You can compare the Content-Length for both successful and failed responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this 
`app.post("/check", function(req, res) {
    var link = req.body.url;
    var opts = {
        uri: link,
        gzip: true
    }
    request(opts, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            res.json({ body: body});
        }
    });
});`